# Eclipse RCP console

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I have integrated  a console to my rcp application but I would like to display some important informations in red colour  rather than in blue but I don't know how to do it(can I add some if conditions?)this the class for my console view .please help me to solve my problem.

```java
public DebugConsole()   
{   
    super("stdio/stderr", null);   

    outMessageStream = newMessageStream();   
    outMessageStream.setColor(Display.getCurrent().getSystemColor(   
            SWT.COLOR_BLUE));   

    errMessageStream = newMessageStream(); 

    errMessageStream.setColor(Display.getCurrent().getSystemColor(   
            SWT.COLOR_RED));   

    System.setOut(new PrintStream(outMessageStream));   
    System.setErr(new PrintStream(errMessageStream));   

}
```

Comment: What Types are your messagestreams of?

Comment: private MessageConsoleStream outMessageStream;   
 private MessageConsoleStream errMessageStream;

Answer (score 1):

Suggest the below.

From your code if `newMessageStream()` method returns valid `MessageConsoleStream` then all `System.out.print` messages will be displayed in BLUE colour and `System.err.print` messages will be displayed in RED colour

1. Use [ConsolePatternListener](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_ui_console_consolePatternMatchListeners.html?cp=2_1_1_137) to display matching messages in
   different colour on console.
2. Change stream colour before you use `System.out.print` or `System.err.print` statements.
   In the last two lines of you code make `PrintSteam` instances as class public fields(or private with getter and setters) and get these streams and set colour. Remember to reset the colour back after you used `System.out.print` or `System.err.print` statement.

```java
public class DebugConsole {

    private PrintStream outStream;
    private PrintStream errStream;

    public DebugConsole() {
        super("stdio/stderr", null);

        outMessageStream = newMessageStream();
        outMessageStream.setColor(Display.getCurrent().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_BLUE));

        errMessageStream = newMessageStream();

        errMessageStream.setColor(Display.getCurrent().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_RED));
        outStream = new PrintStream(outMessageStream);
        errStream = new PrintStream(errMessageStream);

        System.setOut(outStream);
        System.setErr(errStream);
    }

    public PrintStream getOutStream() {
        return outStream;
    }
    public void setOutStream(PrintStream outStream) {
        this.outStream = outStream;
    }
    public PrintStream getErrStream() {
        return errStream;
    }
    public void setErrStream(PrintStream errStream) {
        this.errStream = errStream;
    }       
}
```

Test class:

```java
public class TestConsole {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DebugConsole console = new DebugConsole();
        MessageConsoleStream errStream = (MessageConsoleStream)console.getErrStream();  
        Color oldColor = errStream.getColor();
        errStream.setColor(Display.getCurrent().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_DARK_GREEN));
        //All the below message will be displayed in green color
        System.err.println("This is in green color");
        System.err.println("This is in green color");
        //Reset color back
        errStream.setColor(oldColor);

        //Do the same for output stream         

    }
}
```

Or Use Grep console Plugin [See
    here](http://marian.schedenig.name/projects/grep-console)

Comment: could you clarify your answer please i didn't get it